# Tooltip not working with Angular Material 2.0.0-alpha.9-3 with angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular 2 for my web application and for design purpose I have been using 
**"@angular/material": "2.0.0-alpha.9-3"** but it seems I'm not able to include tooltip and some other components from this.

So far, I have included **md-tab-group** before(couple of years back) and its working fine but when I try to include tooltip no error or no action seems to occur

Is there a way to include these feature to my app?

I tried to find angular material v2.0.0-alpha.9-3 documentation but it shows **404 not found**.

Can upgrading to a newer version break my app?

Comment: Why are you using an extremely outdated version? There's also currently no such documentation for versions before v5, so you have to build the docs yourself!

Comment: Thank you for your resposne @Edric Actually the app was developed couple of years back now we want to upgrade it...
Is it possible to do so?

Comment: It's definitely possible, but depending how the specifics of the app, it could be a large effort. Check out [the Angular update guide](https://update.angular.io/) for more information on changes between your current version and the target version you're upgrading to.